# How can I adopt apps to iOS 13 Dark mode using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

When I don't set the foregroundColor, SwiftUI will adopt my objects' color to Dark Mode automatically when Environment changes. However, when I set the foregroundColor, for example:

```
Text("Jason Parker")
    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
```

SwiftUI will no longer change the color of objects. I heard there are system colours in UIColor but Color of SwiftUI does not include these variables. How can I adopt apps to iOS 13 Dark mode using SwiftUI?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I do it. First, if you wish to use `UIColor` semantics, you can as of... was it beta 5?

```
Color(color: Color(UIColor.systemBackground)
```

But if you want custom colors for your app, you need to tap into the `colorScheme`:

```
@Environment (\.colorScheme) var colorScheme:ColorScheme
```

There's several ways to use it, I may a `Color` extension:

```
extension Color {
    static let yellow = Color.yellow
    static let darkGrey = Color.init(UIColor.darkGray)

    static func backgroundColor(for colorScheme: ColorScheme) -> Color {
        if colorScheme == .dark {
            return yellow
        } else {
            return darkGrey
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Text(""Hello world!").background(Color.backgroundColor(for: colorScheme))
```

Now, obviously this is a simplified color scheme, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can force your app to use only dark mode setting

> window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark

in your SceneDelegate.swift:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    let contentView = LoginView()

    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```